# Qlikview Transform Rows to Columns

Tags: tabular, qlikview

I have table in QlikView like this:

```
---------------------------------
| Limit | Person | Year | Value |
---------------------------------
| L1    | p1     | 2018 | 300   |
| L1    | p1     | 2017 | 200   |
| L1    | p2     | 2018 | 200   |
| L1    | p2     | 2017 | 200   |
| L2    | p1     | 2018 | 100   |
| L2    | p1     | 2017 | 200   |
---------------------------------
```

and I need to convert rows in column. In this example I need to transform `Year` in columns and `Value` in rows, to get a table like this:

```
--------------------------------
| Limit | Person | 2017 | 2018 |
--------------------------------
| L1    | p1     | 200  | 300  |
| L1    | p2     | 200  | 200  |
| L2    | p1     | 200  | 100  |
---------------------------------
```

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try as much as possible to include contents in your question. Links may break over time.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want want the table on the data model or on the chart interface? On the chart interface you can achieve this using a Pivot Table and dragging the Year dimension to the columns.

Comment: on straight table

Comment: I would surely switch the straight table to a pivot table and drag the Year dimension to the columns (simply drag and drop to the first row).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options here:

1) Use SQL style load script with case statements to pivot the data.

2) Use built in transformation wizard to pivot the data. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qlikview/qlikview_rotating_tables.htm

Regards